# How would 2 balls, one on top of the other, rotate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

> A small ball [A] of mass $m$ and radius $r$ is held on a larger ball [B] of radius "100r" and mass "100m" at an angle of 75 degrees from the vertical. The surface of the larger ball is rough and it lies on a rough surface which has sufficient coefficient of friction to ensure pure rolling at all times. Find the minimum value of coefficient of friction between balls [B] and [A] so that ball [A] detaches from ball B at an angle 45 degrees from the vertical after pure rolling on its surface.

I came up with this problem by myself but I'm unable to solve it because both the particles would be rotating here. Since the force acting on ball B is variable, so is the friction and accordingly is its torque. I'm not sure if the conditions are sufficient to calculate the answer. We can probably write 3 equations by applying the conditions of pure rolling on 2 points of ball B (one at its base and other at its point of intersection with ball A) and 1 point on ball A at its intersection with ball B. We might have to apply work energy theorem too. But I'm unable to write down these equations and arrive at an answer. Feel free to take necessary assumptions wherever necessary as I thought of this problem by myself so it might need some refinement.

Comment: please read the site policy regarding 'homework-type' questions: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/

Comment: what inspired you to come up with this question?

Comment: @MartinCR read his last line, the question still sounds very homework-y. maybe the OP should edit to make it in line with the policy

Comment: @AdilMohammed I was initially thinking of a ball rolling on an inclined plane; a case which is very general. I then took it a step further and thought of a movable inclined plane on a smooth surface and conditions of pure rolling of a ball on it. That was simpler because at least the angles weren't changing and we could conserve momentum to calculate velocities at any time. I tried to modify it to make it a problem where even the angles are changing(the normal force on the larger object is variable if component of gravity along normal is changing).That's how i came up with this problem.